# How to remove sshd pts processes in status D without restarting servers

Tags: shell, tty, sshd, proc, pts

Why are these sshd-pts processes stuck in status D? It seems the system load averages are increasing due to these processes. How can I remove them without restarting my server.

(add ppid and etime)

```
[root@manager ~]# ps -eo pid,ppid,user,state,etime,command,wchan |grep sshd |awk -F " " '{if($4=="D")print}'
 3024  7162 root     D 31-00:45:56 sshd: root@pts/10           tty_ldisc_hangup
 3799 23740 root     D 62-03:49:15 sshd: root@pts/7            tty_ldisc_ref_wait
 4883 23740 root     D 29-02:12:59 sshd: root@pts/11           tty_ldisc_ref_wait
 7162 23740 root     D 34-21:39:42 sshd: root@pts/10           tty_ldisc_ref_wait
 8011 15566 root     D 62-21:06:45 sshd: root@pts/4            tty_ldisc_hangup
 9297 29509 root     D 71-21:44:30 sshd: root@pts/5            tty_ldisc_hangup
13927 32658 root     D 48-15:41:05 sshd: root@pts/8            tty_ldisc_hangup
14488     1 root     D 62-17:42:02 sshd: root@pts/6            tty_ldisc_ref_wait
15007 23740 root     D 47-23:40:33 sshd: root@pts/9            tty_ldisc_ref_wait
15566     1 root     D 68-22:23:34 sshd: root@pts/4            tty_ldisc_ref_wait
18017     1 root     D 82-11:50:11 sshd: root@pts/3            tty_ldisc_ref_wait
22081  4883 root     D 24-21:08:20 sshd: root@pts/11           tty_ldisc_hangup
25157 15007 root     D 41-11:34:06 sshd: root@pts/9            tty_ldisc_hangup
28168 18017 root     D 82-11:49:11 sshd: root@pts/3            tty_ldisc_hangup
29509     1 root     D 71-21:47:22 sshd: root@pts/5            tty_ldisc_ref_wait
29718  3799 root     D 61-02:02:54 sshd: root@pts/7            tty_ldisc_hangup
31394 14488 root     D 62-13:38:32 sshd: root@pts/6            tty_ldisc_hangup
32658 23740 root     D 58-21:47:54 sshd: root@pts/8            tty_ldisc_ref_wait
```

stack info

```
[root@manager ~]# cat /proc/3024/stack 
[<ffffffff81396c99>] tty_ldisc_hangup+0xc9/0x220
[<ffffffff8138e4fc>] __tty_hangup+0x30c/0x410
[<ffffffff8138e911>] tty_vhangup_self+0x21/0x50
[<ffffffff8117b043>] sys_vhangup+0x23/0x30
[<ffffffff816d8639>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff

[root@manager ~]# cat /proc/3799/stack 
[<ffffffff813961f0>] tty_ldisc_ref_wait+0x20/0x50
[<ffffffff8138e8b8>] tty_poll+0x58/0x90
[<ffffffff8118f92e>] do_select+0x36e/0x680
[<ffffffff8118fe1b>] core_sys_select+0x1db/0x300
[<ffffffff8118fffa>] SyS_select+0xba/0x110
[<ffffffff816d8639>] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

(Add more info:)

After checking the ppid, I've found that the processes that stuck at `tty_ldisc_hangup` are children of processes that stuck at `tty_ldisc_ref_wait`.

e.g. process 3024 is the child of process 7162. It seems that 7162 is waiting for 3024 to hangup tty.

And according to slm's suggestion, I checked lsof of these processes. Following is the truncated output of 3024 and 7162.

(3024)

```
sshd    3024 root    0u   CHR    1,3      0t0       1028 /dev/null
sshd    3024 root    1u   CHR    1,3      0t0       1028 /dev/null
sshd    3024 root    2u   CHR    1,3      0t0       1028 /dev/null
sshd    3024 root    3u  sock    0,6      0t0 1037695934 protocol: TCP
sshd    3024 root    5r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 1037701548 pipe
sshd    3024 root    6w  FIFO   0,16      0t0 1037701541 /run/systemd/sessions/705007.ref
sshd    3024 root    7w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 1037701548 pipe
sshd    3024 root    9u   CHR 136,10      0t0         13 /dev/pts/10
sshd    3024 root   10r  FIFO    0,8      0t0 2320263517 pipe
sshd    3024 root   11w  FIFO    0,8      0t0 2320263517 pipe
```

(7162)

```
sshd    7162 root    0u   CHR                1,3      0t0       1028 /dev/null
sshd    7162 root    1u   CHR                1,3      0t0       1028 /dev/null
sshd    7162 root    2u   CHR                1,3      0t0       1028 /dev/null
sshd    7162 root    3u  sock                0,6      0t0 1037695934 protocol: TCP
sshd    7162 root    4u  unix 0xffff88069a94e580      0t0 1037701545 socket
sshd    7162 root    5r  FIFO                0,8      0t0 1037701548 pipe
sshd    7162 root    6w  FIFO               0,16      0t0 1037701541 /run/systemd/sessions/705007.ref
sshd    7162 root    7w  FIFO                0,8      0t0 1037701548 pipe
sshd    7162 root    8u   CHR                5,2      0t0       1644 /dev/ptmx
sshd    7162 root   12u   CHR                5,2      0t0       1644 /dev/ptmx
sshd    7162 root   13u   CHR                5,2      0t0       1644 /dev/ptmx
```

checking session info:

```
[root@manager ~]# loginctl session-status 705007
705007 - root (0)
       Since: Thur 2018-06-14 10:10:31 UTC; 1 months 4 days ago
      Leader: 7162 (sshd)
      Remote: 10.161.16.14
     Service: sshd; type tty; class user
       State: active
        Unit: session-705007.scope
              ├─3024 sshd: root@pts/10   
              └─7162 sshd: root@pts/10
```

And the remove ip is actually my host ip.

```
[root@tgdc-manager-machine ~]# hostname -I
10.161.16.14
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767551/how-to-stop-uninterruptible-process-on-linux.

Answer (score 0):

#### Background

By definition anything in status D:

> D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)

Is waiting in a portion of the kernel's code that is not interruptible. Things such as disk I/O. This doesn't mean that you cannot send it a signal via the `kill` command, if just means that it won't act on it, until it's out of this portion of the kernel.

So the hint here is I/O. If these connections are truly waiting on disk I/O, I'd take a look at them using `lsof -p <pid>` to see if there's some path to the HDD that they're blocked on.

#### Triage

```
$ lsof -p 3499
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
sshd    3499 vagrant  cwd    DIR              253,0      239       64 /
sshd    3499 vagrant  rtd    DIR              253,0      239       64 /
sshd    3499 vagrant  txt    REG              253,0   853040 33982191 /usr/sbin/sshd
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    15480 33565594 /usr/lib64/security/pam_lastlog.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    15632 33565575 /usr/lib64/libpam_misc.so.0.82.0
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   309280 33801011 /usr/lib64/security/pam_systemd.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    19600 33565595 /usr/lib64/security/pam_limits.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    11152 33565593 /usr/lib64/security/pam_keyinit.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    40784 33565922 /usr/lib64/security/pam_namespace.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    11200 33565598 /usr/lib64/security/pam_loginuid.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    19760 33565930 /usr/lib64/security/pam_selinux.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    44600 33565499 /usr/lib64/libcrack.so.2.9.0
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    23832 33565556 /usr/lib64/libpwquality.so.1.0.2
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    11232 33565557 /usr/lib64/security/pam_pwquality.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0     6984 33565924 /usr/lib64/security/pam_permit.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    11144 33565597 /usr/lib64/security/pam_localuser.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    11176 33565923 /usr/lib64/security/pam_nologin.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0     6872 33565583 /usr/lib64/security/pam_deny.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    15408 33565935 /usr/lib64/security/pam_succeed_if.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    57728 33565941 /usr/lib64/security/pam_unix.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    11168 33565587 /usr/lib64/security/pam_faildelay.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    15552 33565585 /usr/lib64/security/pam_env.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    15496 33565932 /usr/lib64/security/pam_sepermit.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    62184 33558009 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    68192 33565404 /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1.0.6
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    99944 33565444 /usr/lib64/libelf-0.170.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    19896 33565252 /usr/lib64/libattr.so.1.1.0
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    15688 33565266 /usr/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1.5
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    58728 33565394 /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    11464 33557778 /usr/lib64/libfreebl3.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   251776 33565174 /usr/lib64/libnspr4.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    20040 33565177 /usr/lib64/libplc4.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    15744 33565178 /usr/lib64/libplds4.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   194944 33565179 /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0  1249544 33574183 /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   164288 33565958 /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   323664 33565980 /usr/lib64/libssl3.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   470360 33565368 /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.2k
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   121320 33574189 /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so.3.0.0
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   144792 33565153 /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    88720 33554537 /usr/lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   297360 33800995 /usr/lib64/libdw-0.170.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    19384 33565450 /usr/lib64/libgpg-error.so.0.10.0
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   535064 33565460 /usr/lib64/libgcrypt.so.11.8.2
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    85952 33574789 /usr/lib64/liblz4.so.1.7.5
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   157424 33565398 /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5.2.2
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    44448 33565157 /usr/lib64/librt-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0  1139680 33557999 /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    20032 33565257 /usr/lib64/libcap.so.2.22
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   402384 33565268 /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1.2.0
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    23968 33565452 /usr/lib64/libcap-ng.so.0.0.0
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   117680 33558001 /usr/lib64/libnsl-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0  2173512 33557991 /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    15848 33565175 /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   210840 33565386 /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   963576 33565392 /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   320408 33565382 /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   106848 33565155 /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    41080 33557995 /usr/lib64/libcrypt-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    90664 33565173 /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.7
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    14872 33565161 /usr/lib64/libutil-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    61952 33725051 /usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.10.7
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   352600 33725053 /usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.10.7
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    19776 33557997 /usr/lib64/libdl-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0  2512832 33565366 /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.2k
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   203800 33801008 /usr/lib64/libsystemd.so.0.6.0
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   155784 33565267 /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    61672 33565573 /usr/lib64/libpam.so.0.83.1
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   127096 33565455 /usr/lib64/libaudit.so.1.0.0
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    42520 33565448 /usr/lib64/libwrap.so.0.7.6
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0    11344 33724998 /usr/lib64/libfipscheck.so.1.2.1
sshd    3499 vagrant  mem    REG              253,0   164240 33557984 /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so
sshd    3499 vagrant    0u   CHR                1,3      0t0     5078 /dev/null
sshd    3499 vagrant    1u   CHR                1,3      0t0     5078 /dev/null
sshd    3499 vagrant    2u   CHR                1,3      0t0     5078 /dev/null
sshd    3499 vagrant    3u  IPv4              28862      0t0      TCP localhost.localdomain:ssh->10.0.2.2:49736 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    3499 vagrant    4u  unix 0xffff98d19f296400      0t0    28968 socket
sshd    3499 vagrant    5u  unix 0xffff98d19f010800      0t0    28971 socket
sshd    3499 vagrant    6w  FIFO               0,19      0t0    28964 /run/systemd/sessions/13.ref
sshd    3499 vagrant    7r  FIFO                0,9      0t0    28983 pipe
sshd    3499 vagrant    8w  FIFO                0,9      0t0    28983 pipe
sshd    3499 vagrant    9u  unix 0xffff98d19a775c00      0t0    28984 /tmp/ssh-UEdXO0wvf9/agent.3499
sshd    3499 vagrant   10u   CHR                5,2      0t0     6796 /dev/ptmx
sshd    3499 vagrant   14u   CHR                5,2      0t0     6796 /dev/ptmx
sshd    3499 vagrant   15u   CHR                5,2      0t0     6796 /dev/ptmx
```

#### disk I/O

It's entirely possible that someone may have been in an SSH session and changed directories (`cd`) to some filesystem that may no longer be available or is hung up, which is leading to your status D's.

#### network I/o

The other thought is that the blocked I/O may in fact be network connections to another server, that's blocking.

For the TCP connections that an `ssh` is actively using they'll look like this:

```
sshd    3499 vagrant    3u  IPv4              28862      0t0      TCP localhost.localdomain:ssh->10.0.2.2:49736 (ESTABLISHED)
```

I'd look for this and confirm that you can `ping` these servers, and also that you can `curl -v telnet://<ip>:22` to these servers as well.

Comment: The `wchan` column in the `ps` listing in the original post seems to suggest that the waiting is somehow TTY-related. [This question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/648174/ssh-terminal-hangs-tty-ldisc-hangup) and [this one on Stack Overflow](https://serverfault.com/questions/648174/ssh-terminal-hangs-tty-ldisc-hangup) both relate to a similar problem which was ultimately caused by a `hpsa` kernel module and its interaction with a buggy RAID controller firmware(!).

Comment: @telcoM - agree it's likely pts related, that would show up in the `lsof` output as well.

Comment: The stack trace is unequivocal.  The first process is executing `vhangup()` and is blocked inside the line discipline code.

Comment: add more info and lsof output. These is a TCP connection info. But it's a sock type not IPv4.

Comment: @WenyiLi - I'm showing general approaches to the problem, not exhaustive. In multiple discussions w/ other colleagues there really isn't any way to recover from D state, you're going to have to reboot.